# Chaining a cache() command in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, caching, pyspark, rdd

I'm just beginning to learn about pyspark and am playing around with how to optimize code w/ caching. Does chaining cache() commands make sense? here's what my code looks like

```py
token_count_dict = dict(sorted_tokens_rdd.collect())
tokens = list(token_count_dict.keys())

popular_tokens = uid_txt_rdd.flatMapValues(tok.tokenize)\
    .filter(lambda x: x[1] in tokens)\
    .distinct()\
    .map(lambda x: ((partition[x[0]] if x[0] in partition.keys() else 7, x[1]), 1))\
    .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y)\
    .map(lambda x: (x[0], a_function(x[1], token_count_dict[x[0][1]])))\
    .sortBy(lambda x: (x[0][0], -x[1], x[0][1]))\
    .map(lambda x: (x[0][0], (x[0][1], x[1])))\
    .groupByKey()\
    .map(lambda x: [x[0], list(x[1])])

print(popular_tokens.toDebugString().decode("utf-8"))
```

output is:

```
(2) PythonRDD[149] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[148] at mapPartitions at PythonRDD.scala:122 []
 |  ShuffledRDD[147] at partitionBy at <unknown>:0 []
 +-(2) PairwiseRDD[146] at groupByKey at <ipython-input-24-d694a6d94459>:5 []
    |  PythonRDD[145] at groupByKey at <ipython-input-24-d694a6d94459>:5 []
    |  MapPartitionsRDD[144] at mapPartitions at PythonRDD.scala:122 []
    |  ShuffledRDD[143] at partitionBy at <unknown>:0 []
    +-(2) PairwiseRDD[142] at sortBy at <ipython-input-24-d694a6d94459>:5 []
       |  PythonRDD[141] at sortBy at <ipython-input-24-d694a6d94459>:5 []
       |  MapPartitionsRDD[138] at mapPartitions at PythonRDD.scala:122 []
       |  ShuffledRDD[137] at partitionBy at <unknown>:0 []
       +-(2) PairwiseRDD[136] at reduceByKey at <ipython-input-24-d694a6d94459>:5 []
          |  PythonRDD[135] at reduceByKey at <ipython-input-24-d694a6d94459>:5 []
          |  MapPartitionsRDD[134] at mapPartitions at PythonRDD.scala:122 []
          |  ShuffledRDD[133] at partitionBy at <unknown>:0 []
          +-(2) PairwiseRDD[132] at distinct at <ipython-input-24-d694a6d94459>:5 []
             |  PythonRDD[131] at distinct at <ipython-input-24-d694a6d94459>:5 []
             |  ./hw2-files-10mb.txt MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0 []
             |      CachedPartitions: 2; MemorySize: 2.6 MB; ExternalBlockStoreSize: 0.0 B; DiskSize: 0.0 B
             |  ./hw2-files-10mb.txt HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0 []
```

based on the lineage above, I see several branches that can benefit (?) from caching. So, is the below better spark optimization practice?

Based on the research I've made, the consensus seems to be to cache() where lineage branches. When I time the run of both implementations using %%timeit, there is no difference.

```py
popular_tokens = uid_txt_rdd.flatMapValues(tok.tokenize)\
    .cache()\
    .filter(lambda x: x[1] in tokens)\
    .distinct()\
    .cache()\
    .map(lambda x: ((partition[x[0]] if x[0] in partition.keys() else 7, x[1]), 1))\
    .cache()\
    .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y)\
    .map(lambda x: (x[0], get_rel_popularity(x[1], token_count_dict[x[0][1]])))\
    .cache()\
    .sortBy(lambda x: (x[0][0], -x[1], x[0][1]))\
    .cache()\
    .map(lambda x: (x[0][0], (x[0][1], x[1])))\
    .cache()\
    .groupByKey()\
    .map(lambda x: [x[0], list(x[1])])
```

The output seems to still have a lot of branching

```
(2) PythonRDD[130] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[129] at mapPartitions at PythonRDD.scala:122 []
 |  ShuffledRDD[128] at partitionBy at <unknown>:0 []
 +-(2) PairwiseRDD[127] at groupByKey at <ipython-input-23-5914874b5d65>:5 []
    |  PythonRDD[126] at groupByKey at <ipython-input-23-5914874b5d65>:5 []
    |  PythonRDD[125] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48 []
    |  PythonRDD[124] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48 []
    |  MapPartitionsRDD[123] at mapPartitions at PythonRDD.scala:122 []
    |  ShuffledRDD[122] at partitionBy at <unknown>:0 []
    +-(2) PairwiseRDD[121] at sortBy at <ipython-input-23-5914874b5d65>:5 []
       |  PythonRDD[120] at sortBy at <ipython-input-23-5914874b5d65>:5 []
       |  PythonRDD[117] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48 []
       |      CachedPartitions: 2; MemorySize: 7.4 KB; ExternalBlockStoreSize: 0.0 B; DiskSize: 0.0 B
       |  MapPartitionsRDD[116] at mapPartitions at PythonRDD.scala:122 []
       |  ShuffledRDD[115] at partitionBy at <unknown>:0 []
       +-(2) PairwiseRDD[114] at reduceByKey at <ipython-input-23-5914874b5d65>:5 []
          |  PythonRDD[113] at reduceByKey at <ipython-input-23-5914874b5d65>:5 []
          |  PythonRDD[112] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48 []
          |      CachedPartitions: 2; MemorySize: 193.2 KB; ExternalBlockStoreSize: 0.0 B; DiskSize: 0.0 B
          |  PythonRDD[111] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48 []
          |      CachedPartitions: 2; MemorySize: 188.7 KB; ExternalBlockStoreSize: 0.0 B; DiskSize: 0.0 B
          |  MapPartitionsRDD[110] at mapPartitions at PythonRDD.scala:122 []
          |  ShuffledRDD[109] at partitionBy at <unknown>:0 []
          +-(2) PairwiseRDD[108] at distinct at <ipython-input-23-5914874b5d65>:5 []
             |  PythonRDD[107] at distinct at <ipython-input-23-5914874b5d65>:5 []
             |  PythonRDD[106] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48 []
             |      CachedPartitions: 2; MemorySize: 652.0 KB; ExternalBlockStoreSize: 0.0 B; DiskSize: 0.0 B
             |  ./hw2-files-10mb.txt MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0 []
             |      CachedPartitions: 2; MemorySize: 2.6 MB; ExternalBlockStoreSize: 0.0 B; DiskSize: 0.0 B
             |  ./hw2-files-10mb.txt HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0 []
```

Thanks for helping a noob!

Answer (score 1):

Caching is a choice between saving compute vs consuming storage.  You can't cache everything because that will consume memory and disk. Memory is limited and caching to disk involves IO when you read it back. I will recommend to cache a dataframe which is expensive to build and used more than once.

If it is used only once then I wouldn't cache it even if it is expensive to build because it must be built once to be used. This is why you don't see any benefit in performance because you don't reuse the cached data.

In your example, I will cache the end result after all the filter, sort, map and groupby happened assuming that the whole thing is reused.